# Is it possible to hide joined date of GitHub?

Tags: github

Is it possible to hide the joined date of GitHub?
It seems to not appear on an old account, but it displays on a new account.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have  filled at least one entry in your profile, the joined date will be shown. Otherwise, the order of appearance on the edit profile page determines the information shown. So most people fill Company or Location entries to get rid of the joined date.

Comment: are you sure that it is related to the filling profile data? Actually, in my GitHub profile, I can't see it. Maybe, because, it is an old account. But I still can see the GitHub profiles, which data is filled, but joining date still shown.

Answer (score 2):

On profile pages, the age of the account is shown for the first 30 days e.g. "Joined 2 days ago". Filling in other profile information such as location or company doesn't have any effect on this.

Once the account is older than that the join date is no longer shown in the sidebar of the profile but will still be visible as the first entry in [contribution activity](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/viewing-contributions-on-your-profile#contribution-activity).

This answer is based on experimentation along with [this Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/github/comments/nmoe1p/comment/gzr8o0w/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).